# I want to travel from Bali to West Nusa

Tags: public-transport, ferries, indonesia

I want to travel from Bali to West Nusa.

Is there a direct ferry? Or do I need to travel to Lombok island first, then drive across the island to take another boat?

Comment: At least [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bali-Indonesia/West-Nusa-Tenggara) does not list any direct options but suggest going via Lombok as you say.

Comment: "West Nusa" is not a place.  Do you mean the province of West Nusa Tenggara in general, or its closest island to Bali, Lombok?